# Trouble with Fourier transform of Exp[-Sqrt[x]]

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

First time trying to do something "real" in Mathematica, 
I am having trouble getting it to calculate this Fourier transform.
It runs for a long time, then just prints the input expression.

```
FourierTransform[ Exp[-Sqrt[Wx x^2 + Wy y^2 + Wz z^2]], 
 {x, y, z}, {u, v, w}, 
 Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals, y ∈ Reals, 
   z ∈ Reals,
   Wx ∈ Reals, Wy ∈ Reals, Wz ∈ Reals, 
   Wx > 0, Wy > 0, Wz > 0}
 ]
```

I also tried it as an integral.

I am sure the problem is in me, not in mathematica.

Comment: I also have had some problems (using Mathematica 10.0.1) on this and related examples. I'll post either an answer to this, or a separate question when I have time to look further.

Comment: I'd like to point out that a scaling of variables allows you to reduce this to the Fourier-Bessel Transform of a decaying exponential, which can then be converted into the reciprocal space profile by a scaling. I'll post this as a partial answer in a while.

Comment: I had also tried adding a constant 'a', meaning (briefly) f(r)=exp(- W r + a), which would be a suitable answer in my application if 'a' is set to a small value. Thinking that this would fix the singularity in the derivative at the origin.  It also did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica's `FourierTransform` can be a bit difficult at times, so I'll let someone else address whether your code can be tweaked to work, and instead show how to do it symbolically. Defining
$$f(\mathbf{r})=\exp\left(-|W\mathbf{r}|\right)$$
where
$$W=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \sqrt{w_x} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{w_y} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \sqrt{w_z} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
note that
$$f\left(W^{-1}\mathbf{r}\right)=\exp\left(-|\mathbf{r}|\right).$$
By the scaling property
$$\mathcal{F}\left(f(A\mathbf{r}),\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k}\right)=\frac{1}{\text{det}(A)}\mathcal{F}\left(f(\mathbf{r}),\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k}A^{-1}\right)$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform and $A$ is any matrix, it suffices to compute $$\mathcal{F}\left(\exp\left(-|\mathbf{r}|\right),\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k}\right).$$
Since $\exp\left(-|\mathbf{r}|\right)$ is spherically symmetric, [we obtain the spherical Bessel transform](http://pyoz.vrbka.net/theory/fourier-transformation)
$$\mathcal{F}\left(\exp\left(-|\mathbf{r}|\right),\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k}\right)=\int_0^\infty 4\pi j_0\left(|\mathbf{k}|r\right)r^2\exp(-r)dr=\frac{8\pi}{\left(|\mathbf{k}|^2+1\right)^2}$$
giving the final desired result
$$\mathcal{F}\left(\exp\left(-|W\mathbf{r}|\right),\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k}\right)=\frac{8\pi}{\text{det}(W)\left(|\mathbf{k}W^{-1}|^2+1\right)^2}=\frac{8\pi}{\sqrt{w_xw_yw_z}\left(\frac{k_x^2}{w_x}+\frac{k_y^2}{w_y}+\frac{k_z^2}{w_z}+1\right)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: @bullwinkle: One minor note: the Fourier transform definition in the linked article is nonunitary, whereas Mathematica's definition of `FourierTransform` is unitary, so you should include an extra factor of $(2\pi)^{-3/2}$ (I think).

Comment: Doofus did you use Mathematica for the Bessel integral? If so  could you post your code?  I am trying this... Integrate[
 4 Pi BesselJ[0, Sqrt[u^2 + v^2] r]  Exp[-r] r^2, {r, 0, Infinity},
 Assumptions -> {r \[Element] Reals, u \[Element] Reals, 
   v \[Element] Reals, u >= 0, v >= 0}
 ]

Comment: @bullwinkle: They're spherical Bessel functions $j_n(z)$, not ordinary Bessel functions $J_n(z)$ (see the article I hyperlinked in my answer). In this case $j_0(z)=\text{sinc}(z)=\sin(z)/z$. I used `4 \[Pi] Integrate[(E^-r r Sin[k r])/k, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> k > 0]`.